# Turning on LEDs by interrupt using a button with Raspberry Pi Pico H

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

```
from machine import Pin
interrupt_flag=0
counter=0
buton_1= Pin(5, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
buton_2= Pin(6, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
led= Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)

def callback(buton_1):
    global interrupt_flag
    interrupt_flag=1
    
buton_1.irq(trigger= Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=callback)

def callback2(buton_2):
    interrupt_flag=1
  
buton_2.irq(trigger= Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=callback2)
    
while True:
    counter+=1
    
    if interrupt_flag is 1 and counter==3:
        interrupt_flag=0
        led.toggle()
        interrupt_flag=1
    elif interrupt_flag is 1 and counter==5:
        interrupt_flag=0
        led.toggle()
        interrupt_flag=1
    elif interrupt_flag is 1 and  (buton_1 and buton_2) ==1:
         interrupt_flag=0
         led.toggle()
```

I can't this. What I want to do is literally turn on and off the LED according to the number of cuts. I'm trying to do this with button control.

how can I do that

Comment: What number of cuts?

Comment: Once when it happens 3 times, once when it happens 5 times. When two buttons are pressed at the same time, the LED should light once. @drum

Answer (score 0):

There are some odd aspects to this code.
Your symptoms are unclear but some cleanup would improve matters.
Here are some suggestions.

1. The `while True:` loop should probably [sleep(0.010)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) or something, to avoid pointlessly burning CPU cycles.
2. An address comparison, `interrupt_flag is 1`, is not appropriate. Use an equality test instead: `interrupt_flag == 1`. It might *coincidentally* happen to work due to cPython's implementation detail of caching of small integers, but that's no excuse for using the wrong boolean expression.
3. I see three calls to `led.toggle()`. Consider setting a boolean flag instead, and *at the end* toggle the LED if the flag was set.
4. Testing whether the counter is `in [3, 5]` seems to make little sense, given that it is quickly counting to infinity. Did you want to examine it modulo ten, `counter % 10 == 3`, perhaps? Or reset its value to zero every now and again? Throw in a `print(counter)` debug to see that it's increasing without bound.